# Get DisplayName from GoogleAccountCredential

Tags: java, android, google-calendar-api

I would like to be able to display the display name of the google account.
With GoogleAccountCredential I can obtain the email.
How can I get the displayName from GoogleAccountCredential (email)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [GoogleSignInAccount](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/GoogleSignInAccount#public-method-summary) for that:

```
OptionalPendingResult<GoogleSignInResult> opr = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.silentSignIn(mGoogleApiClient);
if (opr.isDone()) {
    GoogleSignInResult signInResult = opr.get();
    GoogleSignInAccount account = result.getSignInAccount();
    String displayName = account.getDisplayName();
    String givenName = account.getGivenName();
    String familyName = account.getFamilyName();
}
```

Comment: I use a AccountManager to obtain credentials.  google account and pass. IS there way to obtain display name from Googleaccountcredential?